# Even after reinstalling windows, why does explorer.exe like to hang?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, windows-explorer, freeze

I have an LT4009u. Which any sane person would regret buying, but damn it I'll make it work.

Anyways, I upgraded it by buying a 4 GB chip of RAM (up from its original 1 GB), and I put a (rather cheap) SSD In it. The SSD in question is the cheapest one Microcenter had (which is just a re-labeled ADATA S599 drive. Same drive, different sticker).

Now then, windows explorer likes to hang. A lo. Other processes sometimes continue responding but more often than not, the burning ship that is explorer.exe takes down others with it. Eventually stuff starts responding again, but my questions are:

1) Drives are backwards compatible, yes? in the same way a USB 3.0 thumbdrive will work in a USB 1.0 slot (albeit at 1.0 speeds). This probably isn't too important since I don't think any hard drives exist yet that can saturate SATA bandwidths? Regardless, I do believe my SSD is slightly faster than the mobo's data rate.

2) Why does the BIOS and Windows say that there's 4 GB of RAM installed but even on 64-bit windows it only says 3 GB? (

3) Is there any possible way whatsoever to use the extra 1 GB of RAM under 32-bit windows? (Which I am using due to intel's incompetence and/or laziness at not just porting their 32-bit drivers to 64-bit.)

4) How would I go about finding the exact cause of explorer's hanging? If anyone can read Windowsese, here's a log file I got from a program who's purpose is to give information about processes it detects are unresponsive.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10691609/compooter.txt

Comment: Man, I don't think the question is clear in any way, but SOFU forgive me, it's soooo funny!

Comment: create a hang dump of Explorer with ProcDump or Taskmgr and upload the zipped dump. I'll try to analyze it.

Comment: IME, when a clean install of Windows without 3rd party software is hanging or crashing, the problem is bad hardware more often than not.  Most of the remaining cases are bad drivers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Probably because the motherboard doesn't support memory remapping or because memory remapping is disabled in the BIOS. (Which is fine. Memory remapping hurts you with a 32-bit OS anyway.)
3. It's hard to be sure with just the information you've given. What is your exact memory configuration? Where exactly does it say 4GB and where does it say 3GB?
4. Your hang report does tend to suggest a filesystem problem. Did you try a forced `chkdsk`? Do you have any other drives in the system? (It could even be a bad optical disk drive.)

Comment: 1. Oh okay. So a faster-than-supported drive is not an issue. Hooray!
2. Well okay. This machine has a [beep] bios. Googling my arse off hoping I can do a little "hacking". 3. It's just a single 4 GB chip of RAM. The BIOS says there's 4096 installed. Windows says there's also 4096 installed, but only 3091 is usable. even in 64-bit. 4. I tried a chckdsk and there were no problems. Will do another one just in case. The funny thing is that the hanging seems to have abated partially once I updated the SSD's firmware. It still hangs to all hell when booting up, but like 5/10/15 mins later (sometime

Comment: @MajoraLuna you will need to follow these instructions to [merge your duplicate accounts](http://superuser.com/contact/user-merge). This will give you access to comment on answers to your question and edit the original question.